# How to autoplay embed YouTube Video on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, video-embedding

I did search the site before posting this question but I'm looking for a really specific answer.

I'm creating a website with a full width slider. The first slide is the 1 min embed Youtube video. I need the video to autoplay when user arrives on site but I need the video to autostop whenever user scroll down the page or when the slide changes.

Slider.html

```
<!-- start slider -->
       <div id="fwslider">
         <div class="slider_container">
            <div class="slide"> 
                <!-- Slide image -->
               <iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/pTBjHjRhx_Y' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <!-- /Slide image -->
                <!-- Texts container -->
                <div class="slide_content">
                    <div class="slide_content_wrap">
                        <!-- Text title -->
                        <h1 class="title">Run Over<br>Everything</h1>
                        <!-- /Text title -->
                        <div class="button"><a href="#">See Details</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               <!-- /Texts container -->
            </div>
            <!-- /Duplicate to create more slides -->
           <div class="slide">
               <img src="images/slider2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                <div class="slide_content">
                    <div class="slide_content_wrap">
                        <h1 class="title">Run Over<br>Everything</h1>
                        <div class="button"><a href="#">See Details</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/slide -->
        </div>
        <div class="timers"></div>

<!-- Nav Controls -->
  <div class="slidePrev"><span></span></div>
  <div class="slideNext"><span></span></div></div>

       <!--/slider -->
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `?autoplay=1` to ur iframe src like below and this will do the job

```
<iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/pTBjHjRhx_Y?autoplay=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: The OP also wants the video to autostop when the user scrolls down.